# how do I get a default date+time entry in my formtastic form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

I hope you can help me. Many thanks.
I want to get a default value for both inputs.

```
<% semantic_form_for @post do |form| %>  
  <% form.inputs do %>   
    <%= form.input :date %>  
    <%= form.input :time,  :hint => 'enter time'  %>
```

`:start_year` or `:default` doesn't work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you can do:

```
@post.date = Date.today
@post.time = Time.now
```